# bash: nested select menu, only first selection works, the second selection doesnt

Tags: bash, function, shell, select

I have two functions in my script, both are 'select' menus with other 'select' menus nested within.
Both of them work, but only the first selection, not the second selection.
I am obviously doing something wrong on them both.
For now, I will provide just one of my functions as Im guessing that I am making the same mistake on both of them.

**Problem:**
All of the first part of the first menu ("Stream") works perfectly, the second part ("Download") does not though.

**WHY DOESN'T IT WORK? WHAT AM I DOING WRONG??**

```
#!/bin/env bash

MAIN(){
  echo "Stream Or Download?"
  select S_D in 'Stream' 'Download'; do
    case $S_D in
    Stream)
      echo "Audio Or Video?"
      select A_V in 'Audio' 'Video'; do
        case $A_V in
        Audio)
          if [[ "$DOMAIN" =~ 'youtube' ]]; then
            mpv --no-video "$URL"
          else
            streamlink --player='mpv --no-video' "$URL" 720p|& tee /dev/null
          fi
          break 2 ;;
        Video)
          if [[ "$DOMAIN" =~ 'youtube' ]]; then
            am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "$(youtube-dl -f best -g "$URL")" -n is.xyz.mpv/.MPVActivity &> /dev/null
          else
            am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "$(streamlink "$URL")" -n is.xyz.mpv/.MPVActivity &> /dev/null
          fi
          break 2 ;;
    Download)
      echo "Song? Album? Playlist?"
      select S_A_P in 'Song' 'Album' 'Playlist'; do
        case $S_A_P in
        Song)
          echo "Enter Artist:"
          read ARTIST
          echo "Enter Song:"
          read SONG
            youtube-dl --extract-audio --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format m4a --output "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $SONG.%(ext)s" "$URL"
            mid3v2 -v -a "$ARTIST" -S "$SONG" "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $SONG.m4a"
            break 2 ;;
        Album)
          echo "Enter Artist:"
          read ARTIST
          echo "Enter Album:"
          read ALBUM
            youtube-dl --extract-audio --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format m4a --output "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $ALBUM.%(ext)s" "$URL"
            mid3v2 -v -a "$ARTIST" -A "$ALBUM" "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $ALBUM.m4a"
            break 2 ;;
        Playlist)
          echo "Enter Artist/DJ Or Leave It Empty:"
          read ARTIST
          echo "Enter A Title:"
          read TITLE
          if [[ -z "$ARTIST" ]]; then
            youtube-dl --extract-audio --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format m4a --output "$MUSIC_DIR/$TITLE.%(ext)s" "$URL"
            mid3v2 -v -A "$TITLE" "$MUSIC_DIR/$TITLE.m4a"
          else
            youtube-dl --extract-audio --prefer-ffmpeg --audio-format m4a --output "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $TITLE.%(ext)s" "$URL"
            mid3v2 -v -a "$ARTIST" -A "$TITLE" "$MUSIC_DIR/$ARTIST - $TITLE.m4a"
          fi
          break ;;
      esac
      done
      break ;;
    esac
    done
    break ;;
  esac
  done
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of extra code here. Only a select and a nested select are need to illustrate the problem. It's something about `read` reading from std-in, and you'll have to redirect an extra stream to read for the 2nd select, but I'm not quite sure how. I'm sure one of the bash gurus will set you straight. Good idea and Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `case $A_V` block has just 2 options (`Audio`, `Video`), the matching `esac` statement is in the wrong place (messy indentations don't help):

```
    case $S_D in
    Stream)
        ...
        case $A_V in
        Audio)
          ...
        Video)
          ...
                            # `esac` for `case $A_V` should reside on this line
    Download)
        ...
        case $S_A_P in
        Song)
        ...
        Album)
        ...
        Playlist)
        ...
      esac                  # first esac closes `case $S_A_P`
      ...
    esac                    # second esac closes `case $A_V` **THIS IS THE PROBLEM! THIS NEEDS TO BE MOVED JUST BEFORE THE ** `Download` **LINE.**
    ...
  esac                      # last esac closes `case $S_D`
```

**NOTE:** OP will also need to move the associated `done/break` statements with the `esac` statement

**REASON:** Each individual `select` menu must finish with `esac`/`done` at the very end or it will not continue to the next selection. OP didnt close `case $A_V` properly.

Comment: This now works perfectly! thank you so much! @markp-fuso