# How do I use sed to store a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed, terminal

I am trying to use sed to use as input for a variable. The user will choose from a list of files that have numbers before each to identify individual files. Then they choose a number corresponding to a name. I need to get the name of that file. My code is:

```
for entry in *; do
((i++))
echo "$i) $entry: "
done

echo What file # do you want to choose?:
read filenum
fileName=$(./myscript.sh | sed -n "${filenum}p")
echo $fileName  ###this is to see if anything goes into fileName. nothing is ever output
echo What do you want to do with $fileName?
```

Ideally I would use () instead of the backtick but I can't seem to figure out how. I've looked at the links below, but can't get those ideas to work. I believe a problem may be that I am trying to include the **filenum** variable inside my sed.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/storing-output-of-sed-in-a-variable-in-shell-script-499997/

[Store output of sed into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749128/store-output-of-sed-into-a-variable)

Comment: search here for `[bash] select done` and read the bash manual (on-line) about the `select` command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130687/bash-nested-select-menu-only-first-selection-works-the-second-selection-doesn/64137802#64137802 was a very good example that came up just recently. Good luck.

Comment: You shouldn't have backticks around `$filenum`

Comment: If I remove the backticks around $filenum then the output becomes - sed: 1: "2": command expected

Comment: Of course. The command to print line 2 is `2p`, not just `2`.

Comment: Why are you printing a line of a shell script? Did you really mean to print a selected line of the output of the script?

Comment: That sed command is even shown in the question you linked to.

Comment: If you quote your strings, things are much simpler, `echo "$i) $entry: "`

Answer (score 1):

Don't put backticks around `$filenum`. That will try to execute the contents of `$filenum` as a command. Put variables inside double quotes.

And if you do want to nest a backtick expression inside another set of backticks, you have to escape them. That's where `$()` becomes useful -- they nest without any hassle.

When you use `sed -n`, you need to use the `p` command to print the lines that you want to show in the output.

```
fileName=$(sed -n "${filenum}p" myscript.sh)
```

This will put the contents of line `$filenum` of `myscript.sh` in the variable.

If you actually wanted to execute `myscript.sh` and print the selected line of its output, you need to pipe to `sed`:

```
fileName=$(./myscript.sh | sed -n "${filenum}p")
```

Comment: The pipe didn't work. After I input a number like "3", there is no output. It should be a filename?

Comment: Are you sure the script has at least 3 lines of output?

Comment: Can you add `myscript.sh` to the question?